# Prolog: connect4 check diagonal end

Tags: list, prolog

The grid is a list of 7 lists, each list is a column that can contains 6 elements maximum. For victory check, I implemented vertical victory and horizontal victory as below. But I have problems with diagonal check. Any suggestions?

```
% Vertical end check 
isEndVert(Grid, J, N) :-
   getColumn(N, Grid, Column),          
   sublist([J,J,J,J], Column),
   !.
isEndVert(Grid, J, N) :-
   N > 0,
   N1 is N-1,
   isEndVert(Grid, J, N1).

% Horizontal end check
isEndHor(Grid, J, N) :-
   getLine(N, Grid, Line),
   sublist([J,J,J,J], Line),
   !.                                    
isEndHor(Grid, J, N) :- 
   N > 0,
   N1 is N-1,
   isEndHor(Grid, J, N1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have `getLine/3` and `getColumn/3`, let's make `getDiagonal/3`:

```
getDiagonal(Grid, Diagonal) :-
    length(Grid, Columns),
    bagof(Cell,
          I^Row^(between(1, Columns, I),
             (nth1(I, Grid, Row),
              nth1(I, Row, Cell))),
          Diagonal).
```

This gets us the "`I`th" elements of the list for each list numbered from I. This gets us basically the descending diagonal. We need another clause to get the other:

```
getDiagonal(Grid, Diagonal) :-
    length(Grid, Columns),
    bagof(Cell,
          OppositeI^I^Row^(between(1, Columns, I),
             (OppositeI is Columns + 1 - I,
              nth1(I, Grid, Row),
              nth1(OppositeI, Row, Cell))),
          Diagonal).
```

The `^` syntax in here is a quantifier; it basically says to `bagof/3` that we don't consider different instantiations of those variables as necessitating new bags. `findall/3` is more concise but I have a strange preference for `bagof/3`.

Having built that you can probably solve the problem the way you do for the vertical and horizontal cases.

Answer (score 0):

using only list scan, an example of 2 wins, matching forward and backward diagonals:

```
test(J) :- Grid=[
[-,-,-,-,-,-,-],
[-,-,-,-,-,-,-],
[-,-,-,J,-,-,-],
[-,-,J,-,J,-,-],
[-,J,-,-,-,J,-],
[J,-,-,-,-,-,J]
], append(_,[A,B,C,D|_],Grid), % test 4 consecutive rows
  ( start([A,B,C,D],J) ; start([D,C,B,A],J) ).

% on first row of 4, find first matching column 
start([[J|_]|R],J) :- skip1(R,S), diag(S,J). % first found, match diag
start(R,J) :- skip1(R,S), start(S,J).

% each first cell of rows' sequence must match
diag([[J|_]],J). % last row: success 
diag([[J|_]|T],J) :- skip1(T,S), diag(S,J).

% discard first column of each row
skip1([],[]).
skip1([[_|R]|T],[R|S]) :- skip1(T,S).
```

I think it should work independently of the matrix representation being rows or columns oriented. Comments assume a row oriented representation.

Comment: This is pretty opaque to me. I see that it works (kudos!) but the how of it is kind of a head-scratcher.

Comment: I expect nothing less. :)